# Can I install IntelliJidea on freeBSD?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, intellij-idea, freebsd

I use IntelliJidea over Ubuntu.

I'm going to switch from Ubuntu 12.04 to freeBSD and I'd like to make sure that IntelliJidea will work on freeBSD too.

Is Linux IntelliJidea installation package good for freeBSD?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Jetbrains lists the system requirements as

```
GNOME or KDE desktop
1 GB RAM minimum, 2 GB RAM recommended
300 MB hard disk space + at least 1 GB for caches
1024x768 minimum screen resolution
Oracle JDK 6 or JDK 7
```

Gnome and KDE will run on FreeBSD, so I assume that IntelliJidea will also.

Comment: I got 14.1 to boot in a FreeBSD virtual machine, but it was too slow for me to actually figure out if it would compile/run a project.